# Privacy-Badger blocking Cloudinary

Tags: cloudinary

I am trying to upload an image to my cloudinary account, using cloudinary-widget. Now it works nice and easy on chrome, firefox, but **not** on **opera**.

Widget loaded like this in the `<body>` tag:

```
  <script src="//widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Error shown in Opera's console:

> GET https://widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

It is happening as well on a [codepen example](https://codepen.io/eitanp461/pen/gRBeab).

In case it makes a difference, I am using meteor & react. Though I don't think it is related.

**UPDATE:** The problem above happened due to the use of privacy-badger extension. While it is possible to set privacy-badger to allow cloudinary to go through, I guess if I would have users using it, they would just see a broken page and would move on, instead of trying to handle it.

If anyone has a solution already I would like to get help, if not I'll post later own my solution once I have one.

Comment: The Codepen example works for me on Opera (version 51.0.2830.40).

Comment: @RoeeBen-Ari Thanks for commenting, I'll do further checking and will post again

Comment: @RoeeBen-Ari, after you said for you it is working, I found it is because privacy-badger extension. The post updated accordingly.

Comment: @cowCrazy this only happens to users that have cloudinary.com cookies - as cloudinary.com sets some GA cookies that are whole-domain. So the vast majority of your users won't be affected - only people who actually visited cloudinary.com in addition to your app, _and_ also have PB installed.
Cloudinary.com is supposed to be on the PB 'yellow list', you can add your report to https://github.com/EFForg/privacybadger/issues/1153 to help expedite this.

Comment: @RanRubinstein Thanks for the info. I will follow the issue on github.